# Too many open files error when trying to ssh into mac

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh

I ssh'd into my iMac from my laptop fo a while without incident. At some point, I started getting "too many open files" along with other errors:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 31 09:25:00 2020
5.0.7(1)-release
/Users/me/.local/bash.d/exports/10-git.bash: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: line 19: cannot create temp file for here-document: Too many open files
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 8: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 7: sort: command not found
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 7: find: command not found
/Users/me/.local/bash.d/exports/10-git.bash: line 10: declare: cannot use `-f' to make functions
Can't locate warnings/register.pm:   Too many open files at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/vars.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/vars.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 3.
```

It's annoying because command line will hang for several seconds before continuing. But everything works as expected after a bit.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to why I might be seeing these errors? I think it might be some kind of bash sourcing loop or something. Not sure where to begin looking.

Comment: OK, found the problem right away. Had this in one of the bash scripts that I run: 
`declare -fx $(bash -c "source ~/.local/bash.d/functions/10-git.bash; compgen -A function")`. After removing the issue cleared up.

Comment: Great find. If you would put that in as the answer, I’m sure people will learn and appreciate when you check it as solved.

Comment: Do you know exactly why that would cause the issue?

Comment: It has something to do with "cannot make pipe for command substitution" error, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The following line in one of my bash scripts was the problem:

`declare -fx $(bash -c "source ~/.local/bash.d/functions/10-git.bash; compgen -A function")`.

I'm not sure why it results in the error, however.